# How to Change the permalink of new posts while keeping the existing permalink for existing posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, blogs, permalinks

I want to change the permalink of new posts while keeping the existing permalink for all old posts for a wordpress based blog in order to retain the backlink power and social sharing score. I have searched the whole wordpress plugin directory and found only one plugin called [**Advanced Permalinks**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/). I tried this plugin but couldn't get the required resutls. It gives 404 error for all previous posts.

Could you any body help me in this regard?

Comment: I'd love to help, but what kind of help could I give you since you haven't posted any before or after examples?

Comment: May be an `.htaccess` trick can solve the problrm. Post your old `url`'s example.

Answer (score 0):

you must set default setting at the beginning and put page id and post id like **?page_id** or **?p** on the page or post then change the permalink option from setting. Wordpress change permalink at run time from default setting.

Comment: Well, I couldn't get your point, or you couldn't get my point. I know Wordpress changes the permalink at run time and if I change the permalink in Settings it will change the permalink for all posts. But I want to keep the existing permalink for existing posts and only want to change the permalink for all new posts.

Comment: Page_id and p is the default id what wordpress know. My point was change permalinks option to default setting. Note down all of the page/post ids and put whereever its necessary(Menu or post inside of the content). Then change the permalink setting again into custom setting and put what name you want for page/post. Then after clicking Wordpress will call the page/post according to their id and then on rule it will change the permalink according to yours on runtime.